# Does Oracle's JavaCard SDK allow one to develop simtoolkit

Tags: javacard, sim-toolkit

I am trying to develop a SIMToolkit application.

i am complete new to this. I want to know what IDEs can be used to develop STK apps for SIM Cards.

Also I would like to know if JavaCard SDK allows to access call-related functions in STK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it supports. You may use Gemalto's IDE which is actually an Eclipse integrated with JavaCard SDK. It is a pretty well-developed IDE which also supports STK apps for SIMCards with pretty much good ready-to-use examples.

Answer (score 0):

All the APIs are documented in ETSI 102 241 specification. You don't need Gemalto's super expensive SDK. ETSI web site will provide all the documentation and JAR files.